# npm run build does not considers eslintrc.json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, package.json, npm-build

I m working on reactjs web app, which has eslintrc.json file. In this file I have set few eslint rules off/warn so as to skip them instead of error. npm run lint works fine locally, but during build it gives eslint errors.

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
"build": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
 "lint": "eslint .",
.
.
.
}

//eslintrc
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "double",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/static-property-placement": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "warn",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "default-param-last": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "endOfLine": "auto" }],
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "import/no-cycle": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": 0,
    
  }
}
```

> Above are the file with eslint rules and scripts mentioned

Comment: show us your  eslint.json and tsconfig if applicable

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski please check the updated ask

Comment: What errors do you see?

Comment: your file should be called `.eslintrc.json` and not `eslintrc.json`. Is it your case?

Comment: its .eslintrc.json

Comment: I'm mostly backend, but isn't eslint something embedded in React and therefore not configurable unless you eject?  Just a thought.  Not my area of expertise.